# Django Howto Filter out the users that belongs to a particular country and not all users

Tags: django, django-models

Apologize if the code below is not up to a decent programer, as i am not related to computers at all, but i would like to automate a tedious process and i find Django just interesting.. and for the life of me i can not just simply find the answer.

Having the following models.py i would like to filter out the users that belongs to a particular country and not all users, and save this information on a sqlite3 db

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Countries Uploaded'

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    cUsers = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Users on a country'

class GoalsinCountry(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(VideoTopic)
    'HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SEE THE USERS IN EACH COUNTRY'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Goals Topic'
```

Would this be possible to do with Django?
is there any working example?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Users.objects.exclude(cUsers__name='Some Country')
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Thanks @zubair89. For some crazy reason, I was thinking in terms of a reverse relationship. Need more caffiene ;)

Comment: class GoalsinCountry(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    gUser = models.ForeignKey(Users.objects.exclude(cUsers__name=Country.name))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

I am getting 
AssertionError: ForeignKey([<Users: USA1>, <Users: USA2>, <Users: Spain1>]) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
I will have to do more googling  - thanks for pointing in the correct direction!

Comment: Make sure your model's `ForeignKey` field is set to just `Country`, not something like `Country.objects.all()`.

Comment: Thank you Chris, i am sorry but i do not really get it, apoligize if this one is very easy, do you have any link handy how to do this - i tested this on the shell and it works, but not for me using models.py  Thank you for your help

Comment: Based on your error message, your foreign key field is receiving a queryset of `Users`, instead of just a model class. The first parameter to `ForeignKey` must be a simple model class like `Users` or `Country`, etc.

Comment: if i use gUser = models.ForeignKey(Users)  i get all users listed, is there any way to filter out Users that belong to the country selected in the combo box?   Do you have a complete example of this handy please?  Thanks for your support

Comment: If you really need help with that, you should open a new question, but short and sweet, you'll need AJAX to accomplish that. There's dozens of questions to that effect already here on StackOverflow.